# TestNG issue when executing in parallel and with "priority"

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, testng

I have 2 classes.

Class 1:

```java
@Test
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("test1-1");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void test2(){
    System.out.println("test2-1");
}

@Test(priority = 6)
public void test3(){
    System.out.println("test3-1");
}

@Test(priority = 9)
public void test4(){
    System.out.println("test4-1");
}
```

Class 2:

```java
@Test
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("test1-2");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void test2(){
    System.out.println("test2-2");
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void test3(){
    System.out.println("test3-2");
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void test4(){
    System.out.println("test4-2");
}
```

XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Smoke" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="5" >
    <test name="GalaxyS7">
        <classes>
            <class name="TempTest.ClassTest1"/>
            <class name="TempTest.ClassTest2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And when I execute test expected output is:

> test1-1
>   test2-1
>   test3-1
>   test4-1
>   test1-2
>   test2-2
>   test3-2
>   test4-2

But actual output is:

> test1-1
>   test1-2
>   test2-1
>   test2-2
>   test3-2
>   test4-2
>   test3-1
>   test4-1

But when I removing `parallel="tests"`, execution as expected. When I removing *priorities* but `parallel="tests"` stays in XML - execution as expected. But I'm trying to run my tests in parallel and have priorities there as well.

Is it a bug in TestNG or I'm missing something?

Any help is appreciated. My goal is to run all test cases from the first class and then from the 2nd class.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell you seem to be expecting that each instance of an object has it's own set of `priorities` when running in parallel mode, while your test suite treats priorities as global variables, also when priorities are equal it handles then in a top down matter (`TempTest.ClassTest1` then `TempTest.ClassTest2`).

tl;dr:
`priority` is used on a global scale, not on an instance one.

Comment: From my experience `priorities` should work for each test case. And they worked before, not in parallel mode. I found how to resolve it by ` group-by-instances="true" ` . But still when I put `preserve-order="true"` it does not do anything

Comment: So after looking at the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) it appears that there are different parallel modes, in mode `tests` it will run all of the classes in the same `<test>` block on the same thread, if you want to run each each class or object in there own thread simultaneously you can use either `parallel="classes"` or `parallel="instances"`.